# microsoft access 2010: Private Sub Form_Load() not running, .setFocus not acknowleged.

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

So I am trying to create a login form for a database application and I used this article as my guide.

> http://accesshosting.com/create-login-form-ms-access

I followed the steps to the best of my knowledge. However, in creating the vba code for the on click procedure for the "Ok" button for the login form. using the code in the webpage I receive an error on the Private Sub Load_Form part of the codeblock. Other users seemed to have issues with this part as well.

The code in which the error is thrown is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
End Sub
```

.SetFocus is highlighted in this case and error message is shown below.

`method or data member not found`

I tried researching this question and I saw that there might be an issue with naming of the controls. However, the names all matched up. When i typed Me.txtUsername it popped up with intellisense. However the .setFocus didn't appear as I was typing it.

Not sure what's up. The datatypes for each field are as follows.

userName: text, userLogin: text, userID:number, password: text

Short Version: the form cant load and its because .setFocus isn't accepted as a method. Why?

Comment: it is possible that the _txtUserName_ control does not exist at the time when the code runs. is there another event handler like _Form_Open_ , where you can run the code? i believe that Access has a few.

Comment: @jsotola I should mention that I am a beginner so I am not sure what Form_Open is. I'll do some research on that.

Comment: go to the VBA editor, to the Form_Load code that you posted in your question. ... at top of the code window, you will see two dropdown selection boxes. the one on left will say _Form_, the one on right should be _Load_. ... click the dropdown arrow on the right box and you should see a list of "event handler" names. ... if you click on one, "Open" for example, you should see a new _Sub Form_Open_. any code you put into that sub, will run when the form is opened.  each of the other "handlers" will run code, depending on the event that is happening to the form